# Is possible to look (externally) to database during tests?

Tags: django

I'm trying to write a test -

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class MyTests(TestCase):

  def _create_person_object(self):
    person = Person(email='test@example.com', password='test')
    person.save()
    return

  def _login():
    self.client.post('/login/', {'email': 'test@example.com', 'password' : 'test'})
    return

  def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()  

  def test_login(self):
    self._create_person_object()
    self._login()
    input('wait and enter')
  #  person = Person.object.get(email ='test@example.com')
  #  self.assertEqual(person.password, 'test') # 

    response = self.client.get('/denied_area/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

**UPDATE**
I forgot about transactions, so it looks that it is impossible to look into database during test. Am I right?

Comment: I think it does but then it removes it. Your problem is that person.password is hashed https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/auth/passwords/

Comment: You may be right, but I create Object Person with password test, and tried to check it with the same password. So I want to see what is inside the table - thats why i put input('wait and enter')

Comment: You create it with password 'test', then your test fails because the password is not hashed and django freaks out, then it removes everything from the db, then you go manually and see an empty db. I think that's what's happening. Se Daniel Roseman's answer.

Comment: It shouldn't remove it (not in this moment) but @DanielRoseman points, that transaction which isn't complete would show nothing in database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, items are saved into the database (although it flushes the db before each test).

Your error is happening because you are saving a plain text password, but Django's auth framework will always test against a hashed password. You should always create users via the `create_user` manager method, which takes care of hashing the password for you:

```
def _create_person_object(self):
    Person.objects.create_user('test', email='test@example.com', password='test')
```

(Note that you don't need return statements at the end of each function if you're not actually returning a value.)

Comment: Yes, it should flush db, but i try to break it earlier - look at input

Comment: And I don't want to use create_user - this is only example - I want to look into test database what is saved into database during test

Comment: It's not clear from your code, but it looks as though you are just using `input` to pause the program and then inspecting the db separately, eg via a db shell. That won't work because of transaction isolation. Instead, use `pdb` in your test to add a breakpoint and query the models from there.

Comment: TRANSACTION! I forget about it!

Answer (score -2):

Django for tests is trying to delete old database and create a new one.

So when you run tests, it is trying to delete whatever database you have set up in your settings.py file, create it, run migrations, run tests.

For this approach I recommend doing something like this:

```
if any([arg in sys.argv for arg in ['jenkins', 'test']]):
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'default.db'),
        'TEST_NAME': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'default.db'),
    }

    REST_FRAMEWORK = {}

else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
            'NAME': 'your_database_name',
            'USER': 'database_user',
            'PASSWORD': 'database_password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',  # or some other host

        }
    }
```

so when you run command `./manage.py test` it will automatically run tests on your default.db database.

Comment: I'm definetly sure,that django doesn't delete my database - it creates new with prefix test_, flushes in each test and drops whole database after whole test- of course it's quite good to run test on sqlite in memory (much faster) but now i need to look into test database during test